# Impressão Direta PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, shell, impressão

Oi, preciso de alguma solução para imprimir diretamente na impressora um pdf, sem abrir caixas de dialogo e sem usar o adobe, o pdf foi gerado com a biblioteca pdfsharp, posso até usar bibliotecas mas precisa ser free.
Tentei usar RawPrinterHelper, porém só imprime os bytes do pdf.
Tentei:
 `dll.ShellExecuteA(0, "print", filePath, null, null, 0);
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShellExecute")]
            public static extern int ShellExecuteA(int hwnd, string lpOperation,
         string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);`
mas não funcionou, tentei também usar File.Copy passando o arquivo e nome da impressora e não deu certo, alguém pode me dar uma solução diferente, ou se estou fazendo alguma coisa de errado em uma dessas que tentei me ajudar.Estou usando o WINDOWS10

Comment: Você precisa renderizar as páginas do PDF em imagens e imprimir as imagens, tem um monte de bibliotecas que fazem isso, mas a maioria é paga. Dá uma pesquisada...

Comment: você pode usar o Sumatra PDF, e passar por linha de comando: https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments.html ou usar o Spire https://github.com/eiceblue/Spire.PDF-for-.NET

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda, vou pesquisar e tentar suas sugestões

Comment: Obrigada pelas sugestões, usei o Sumatra e funcionou muito bem